# How to use Spring Boot with the Amazon Neptune database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I am using Amazon Neptune for my application. So I want to know if there is a way to use
Spring Boot (Java) to connect and use data from queries in Neptune workbench for my app. 
I have successfully connected to Neptune database using Java core with Visual Studio Code
but I can't find any documentation that clearly describes this procedure for Spring Boot.
Can some help me in this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say Spring Boot, are you building a micro service or a container that uses Spring Boot or are you looking for something more?

Comment: Uhm I am building a monolothic application by using spring boot to connect to neptune database. The issue here is how to connect to neptune through file.properties

Answer (score 2):

To use Neptune with springboot you have to add the configuration file like this below.

```
@Configuration
public class NeptuneConfigExample {


@Bean
public Cluster cluster() {
    return Cluster.build()
            .addContactPoint("your-neptune-instance-here.xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com")
            .port(8182)
            .enableSsl(true)
            .keyCertChainFile("./cert/SFSRootCAG2.pem") // download it from https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/SFSRootCAG2.pem 
            .maxConnectionPoolSize(5)
            .maxInProcessPerConnection(1)
            .maxSimultaneousUsagePerConnection(1)
            .create();
    }
}
```

For reference - [click](https://codetinkering.com/aws-neptune-example-tinkerpop/)

Comment: Thanks @pranav suresh  but I got an error that keyCertChainFile is deprecated

Comment: You only need to provide your own cert if you are unable to use the default one. In many cases you can just leave that part of the builder out. It was replaced by use of the Java Keystore many TinkerPop releases back. So to avoid the deprecation just use the new builder option and remove the deprecated one or just remove that step altogether and use the default cert.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs help, I will recommend using the neo4j driver to connect to the Neptune instance and cypher dsl to easily build cypher queries.
You cannot use Spring Data to connect to your Neptune cluster, but, as I have read somewhere, they are planning to support Neptune in the future.
For now, you can use the bolt protocol.

Here is the list of the libs that you will need:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>2023.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.76</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Besides these, I recommend you have 2 separate connections for writer and reader endpoints.
Here, in this code portion, you should only set your endpoint and port:

```
@Configuration

public class MyNeptuneConfig {

    @Value("${neptune.endpoint.writer}")
    private String writerEndpoint;

    @Value("${neptune.port}")
    private int neptunePort;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenManager writerAuthTokenManager() {
        Map<String, org.neo4j.driver.Value> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(SCHEME_KEY, Values.value("basic"));
        map.put(PRINCIPAL_KEY, Values.value("username"));
        map.put(CREDENTIALS_KEY, new StringValue(getSignedHeaderForWriterEndpoint()));
        map.put(REALM_KEY, Values.value("realm"));
        return AuthTokenManagers.bearer(() -> {
            InternalAuthToken token = new InternalAuthToken(map);
            log.info("Creating new AuthTokenManager.");
            return token.expiringAt(ZonedDateTime.now().plusMinutes(5L).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        });
    }

    @Bean
    public Driver neptuneWriterDriver(AuthTokenManager writerAuthTokenManager) {
        return GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://" + writerEndpoint + ":" + neptunePort,
                writerAuthTokenManager,
                Config.builder()
                        .withConnectionLivenessCheckTimeout( 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES )
                        .withEncryption()
                        .withTrustStrategy(Config.TrustStrategy.trustSystemCertificates())
                        .build());
    }

    private String getSignedHeaderForWriterEndpoint() {
        Request<Void> request = new DefaultRequest<>("neptune-db");
        request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
        request.setEndpoint(URI.create("bolt://" + writerEndpoint + ":" + neptunePort));
        request.setResourcePath("/opencypher");

        final AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
        signer.setRegionName(Region.EU_WEST_1.toString());
        signer.setServiceName(request.getServiceName());
        signer.sign(request, new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials());

        return getAuthInfoJson(request);
    }

    private String getAuthInfoJson(final Request<Void> request) {
        final Map<String, Object> obj = new HashMap<>();
        obj.put(AUTHORIZATION, request.getHeaders().get(AUTHORIZATION));
        obj.put("HttpMethod", request.getHttpMethod());
        obj.put(X_AMZ_DATE, request.getHeaders().get(X_AMZ_DATE));
        obj.put(HOST, request.getHeaders().get(HOST));
        obj.put(X_AMZ_SECURITY_TOKEN, request.getHeaders().get(X_AMZ_SECURITY_TOKEN));

        return new Gson().toJson(obj);
    }
}
```

The same logic is for the reader Driver.

To write to Neptune, create a session on the writer driver, open a transaction, and run the query.

```
public void writeToNeptune(String label, Map<String, String> properties) {
    try (Session session = neptuneWriterDriver.session()) {
        session.executeWriteWithoutResult(tx -> {
            final Node node = Cypher.node(label)
                    .named("n")
                    .withProperties(properties);

            String query = Cypher.merge(node).build().getCypher();
            tx.run(new Query(query));
        });
    } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
        neptuneWriterDriver.close();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To connect to Neptune

Install Apache Maven on your EC2 instance. First, enter the following to add a repository with a Maven package:

```
sudo wget https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache- 
maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache- 
maven.repo
```

Enter the following to set the version number for the packages:

```
sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache- 
maven.repo
```

Then you can use yum to install Maven:

```
 sudo yum install -y apache-maven
```

This example was tested with Java 8 only. Enter the following to install Java 8 on your EC2 instance:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-devel
```

Enter the following to set Java 8 as the default runtime on your EC2 instance:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

When prompted, enter the number for Java 8.

Enter the following to set Java 8 as the default compiler on your EC2 instance:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config javac
```

When prompted, enter the number for Java 8.

In a new directory, create a pom.xml file, and then open it in a text editor.

Copy the following into the pom.xml file and save it (you can usually adjust the version numbers to the latest stable version):

```
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 https://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
 <artifactId>RDFExample</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>RDFExample</name>
<url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>rdf4j-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>3.6</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.amazonaws.App</mainClass>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
       </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
 </project>
```

Note
If you are modifying an existing Maven project, the required dependency is highlighted in the preceding code.

To create subdirectories for the example source code (src/main/java/com/amazonaws/), enter the following at the command line:

```
mkdir -p src/main/java/com/amazonaws/
```

In the src/main/java/com/amazonaws/ directory, create a file named App.java, and then open it in a text editor.

Copy the following into the App.java file. Replace your-neptune-endpoint with the address of your Neptune DB instance.

```
package com.amazonaws;

import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.Repository;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.http.HTTPRepository;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sparql.SPARQLRepository;

import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.RDF4JException;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.RepositoryConnection;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.TupleQuery;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.TupleQueryResult;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.BindingSet;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryLanguage;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Value;

public class App
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String sparqlEndpoint = "https://your-neptune- 
  endpoint:port/sparql";
    Repository repo = new SPARQLRepository(sparqlEndpoint);
    repo.initialize();

    try (RepositoryConnection conn = repo.getConnection()) {
       String queryString = "SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } 
    limit 10";

       TupleQuery tupleQuery = 
 conn.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString);

       try (TupleQueryResult result = tupleQuery.evaluate()) {
          while (result.hasNext()) {  // iterate over the result
               BindingSet bindingSet = result.next();

               Value s = bindingSet.getValue("s");
               Value p = bindingSet.getValue("p");
               Value o = bindingSet.getValue("o");

               System.out.print(s);
               System.out.print("\t");
               System.out.print(p);
               System.out.print("\t");
               System.out.println(o);
          }
       }
    }
}
}
```

Use the following Maven command to compile and run the sample:

```
 mvn compile exec:java
```

Comment: That is actually the SPARQL example from the Neptune docs. The question poster is using Gremlin.