# AWS Neptune - Open Cypher Connectivity

Tags: amazon-neptune, bolt

How to connect to AWS Neptune using bolt protocol?
Followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-opencypher-bolt.html and couldn't succeed. What is `AuthTokens.none()` mean here?

Tried https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-opencypher-bolt.html
Seeing exception
`org.neo4j.driver.exception.DatabaseException: "Unexpected server exception 'MissingAuthenticationTokenException'"`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does your database have IAM authentication enabled? If yes it will be expecting requests to be signed using SigV4

Comment: Yes it has IAM authentication enabled. But from the above example how do i pass Sigv4 headers?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Using java language

Comment: And you looked at this example but it did not work for you ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-opencypher-bolt.html#access-graph-opencypher-bolt-java-iam-auth

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69747333/how-to-use-spring-boot-with-the-amazon-neptune-database/78172661#78172661), maybe it would help you.